# How to parse Jsx String with expressions using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is converting static html content properly but it is unable to evaluate expressions.

[image]

**output:**

[image]

How to evaluate expressions as well using dangerouslySetInnerHTML ?

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `{some expression}` with the evaluated content.

The example below uses [`string-math`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-math) to turn the template html into the intended result. Your implementation would do this transformation for the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

It uses a regex to find { something }. The `.slice(1, -1)` is needed to slice off the `{` and `}`.

```js
const templateStr = '<h2>Math --> {1 + 1}</h2>'

document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = templateStr.replace(/{[^}]+}/g, str => stringMath(str.slice(1, -1)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/string-math@1.2.2/string-math.js"></script>
<div id='div'></div>
```